# MySQL return data when case is not found

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelize.js

Hi can anyone help me on how to add case when data is not found, lets say I'm trying to sum data in StoreId `(1,2,3)`, but data for StoreId 3 is not found/0/null etc. But I still want it to return 0.0

here is my query

```
select s.location, temp3.c from (
    select temp1.StoreId, 100*temp2.vis/temp1.pass as c from
    (select sum(passerBy) pass, StoreId from TemporaryAriadneData
    where StoreId in (${StoreId})
    And DATE_ADD(ariadne_date , INTERVAL 2 HOUR) between '${start_date}' AND '${end_date}'
    group by StoreId) temp1
    inner JOIN
    (select sum(visitor) vis, StoreId from
    (select *, str_to_date(CONCAT( CONCAT( date, ' '), time), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS date_time from ReportAriadneMaps
    where StoreId in (${StoreId})) as temp
    WHERE date_time between '${start_date}' AND '${end_date}'
    group by StoreId) temp2
    on temp1.StoreId = temp2.StoreId) temp3
    left JOIN Stores s
    on s.id = temp3.StoreId
    order by location;
```

result is like below:

[image]

what I expect is as below:

[image]

Edited:

Result solution from @gotqn
`${StoreId}` = (9,11,12)

[image]

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the places of your base query and the `LEFT JOIN` query. You need all stores, so you need to start with the `stores` table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  s.location,
                 IFNULL(temp3.c, 0.0) AS c
FROM stores s
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT temp1.storeid,
            100*temp2.vis/temp1.pass AS c
    FROM      
    (
        SELECT Sum(passerby) pass,
              storeid
        FROM temporaryariadnedata
        WHERE storeid IN (${storeid})
            AND date_add(ariadne_date , INTERVAL 2 hour) BETWEEN '${start_date}' AND      '${end_date}'
        GROUP BY storeid
    ) temp1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT sum(visitor) vis,
                storeid
        FROM     
        (
            SELECT *,
                str_to_date(concat( concat( date, ' '), time), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS date_time
            FROM   reportariadnemaps
            WHERE  storeid IN (${storeid})
        ) AS temp
        WHERE    date_time BETWEEN '${start_date}' AND      '${end_date}'
        GROUP BY storeid
    ) temp2
    ON  temp1.storeid = temp2.storeid
) temp3
    ON s.id = temp3.storeid
 WHERE  s.id IN (${storeid})
ORDER BY  location;
```

Comment: YES MAN IT WORKED, I LOVE YOU. YOU SAVED MY WORK AND LIFE!